# How do I distribute my Android Wear to alpha/beta users on Google Play Store?

Tags: android, wear-os

I am testing my application and am in Alpha mode.  My app is approved and I can find it in alpha mode in the Play Store.  However, the 'wear' portion of my app is not being automatically installed to the wear.

My wear app currently has minimal functionality, so the "opt-in" for the wear keeps getting denied. I would still like to be able to package my minimal wear app for my alpha users, but it doesn't seem to be working.  Any ideas how I can get auto-install of the wear-portion of the app?

Here are my files currently:

/build.gradle

```
// Used in 'mobile' and 'wear' submodules
def versionMajor() { 0 }
def versionMinor() { 0 }
def versionPatch() { 8 }

def gitVersion() {
    def process = "git rev-list master --first-parent --count".execute()
    return process.text.toInteger()
}

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

/mobile/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kamil.coach"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode gitVersion()
        versionName "${versionMajor()}.${versionMinor()}.${versionPatch()}"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'APK META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'APK META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
}

if(project.hasProperty("MyProject.signing") && new File(project.property("MyProject.signing") + ".gradle").exists()) {
    println "mobile applying gradle file"
    apply from: project.property("MyProject.signing") + ".gradle";
} else {
    println "mobile not applying gradle file"
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':core')
    wearApp project(':wear')
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0"

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.3.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'
    compile 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.0.Final'

    compile 'com.uservoice:uservoice-android-sdk:+'

    compile(name:'cloud-release', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'auth-release', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'core-release', ext:'aar')
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

/wear/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kamil.coach"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode gitVersion()
        versionName "${versionMajor()}.${versionMinor()}.${versionPatch()}"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'APK META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'APK META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
}

if(project.hasProperty("MyProject.signing") && new File(project.property("MyProject.signing") + ".gradle").exists()) {
    println "wear applying gradle file"
    apply from: project.property("MyProject.signing") + ".gradle";
} else {
    println "wear not applying gradle file"
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':core')
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.3.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'

    compile(name:'cloud-release', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'auth-release', ext:'aar')
    compile(name:'core-release', ext:'aar')
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

/core/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'


    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.+'
}
```

/mobile/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.kamil.coach"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:name=".mobile.MobileKamilApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CoachTheme"
        >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        .
        .
        .
    </application>

</manifest>
```

/wear/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.kamil.coach"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

    <application
        android:name="com.core.KamilApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault"
        >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        .
        .
        .
        .

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was embedding an aar file which was causing the permissions error.
I had to copy the permissions from within that aar file into my mobile app.

I solved this by using 'adb logcat' on the wear as my mobile-release.apk tried to install from the wear and found out what the issue was.

Answer (score 1):

The wear app must be packaged within the main app, it isn't distributed separately.  You just upload the release apk for the mobile app to the Play Store alpha channel as normal.

Both apps must have the same package name, be signed with the same key and within the mobile gradle depencies you must include the wearable project

```
wearApp project(':wearable')
```

See the full Google docs for more details.
http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html

Comment: I am doing all of these things.  In regards to "Both apps must be signed with the same key"...doesn't Gradle already sign my wear app automatically when I: "Build -> Generate Signed APK" mobile-relase.apk.  ?

Comment: No, that won't sign the wear part of it.
You're best not to use the UI based signing within Android Studio but to sign within both of your build.gradle files so every time you do a release build they both get signed, then merged into the mobile apk.
Here's a good guide I used for signing my apps with every time I build.
https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/22/handling-signing-configs-with-gradle/

Comment: Thanks. I created these build files successfully and put the signing into the mobile and wear... But it's still not working.

Comment: Couple of things to check; did you add the wearapp project mentioned above into your mobile dependencies section of your build.gradle, did you just upload the mobile apk, have your alpha users joined the g+ community and also signed up for alphas using the link available in the play store dev console you should have given them, and finally have you got them to recync apps?

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out here, I greatly appreciate it.  I have done all these things you mentioned, but the wear app still doesn't download unto their wear device.  I also added my files to this question for clarity purposes.

Comment: Permissions must be the same on both wearable and handheld sides.

Comment: The application name must match on both apps.  Permissions seem fine as you have included all the wear ones within the mobile app.

Comment: adb logcat displays: W/WearablePkgInstaller(  923): Wearable com.kamil.coach has a permission "android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" that is not granted in the host application.  But I actually don't have that permission anywhere, i've tried adding it and removing it but the error message keeps showing up for some reason

Comment: Could the core or retrofit require it.  Add it to both wear and mobile manifests to make sure.